# Is there a built-in function to sort and filter a python list in one step?

Tags: python

Given a directory of files all with numeric names, I currently sort and filter the directory list in two steps.

```
#files = os.listdir(path)
files = ["0", "1", "10", "5", "2", "11", "4", "15", "18", "14", "7", "8", "9"]

firstFile =  5
lastFile  = 15

#filter out any files that are not in the desired range
files = filter(lambda f: int(f) >= firstFile and int(f) < lastFile, files)

#sort the remaining files by timestamp
files.sort(lambda a,b: cmp(int(a), int(b)))
```

Is there a python function that combines the filter and sort operations so the list only needs to be iterated over once?

Comment: I doubt there's a python library way to do it. You might find a recipe on activestate or google. Or you could definitely write your own. But is this a bottleneck or are you prematurely optimizing?

Comment: @Falmarri list comprehensions and generator expressions solve this problem elegantly and efficiently. I suppose that's not library, but it is language.

Comment: @Rafe: He's not asking to do it in one line, he's asking to do it in one pass of the list.

Comment: @Falmari: and the only solution to that would be to fix his input.

Comment: A faster and more concise sort would be: `files.sort(key=int)`.  Using `key` means each item is converted to integer just one time, rather than for each compare.

Comment: Sorting is worse than O(n) to begin with--there's little benefit in taking an O(n log n) algorithm and eliminating one O(n).

Comment: @Steven: Thanks for the 'key' tip.
@Glenn Maynard: Excellent point.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Those are orthogonal tasks, I don't think they should be mixed. Besides, it's easy to filter and sort separately in one line with generator expressions

```
files = sorted( (f for f in files if firstFile <= int(f) < lastFile), key=int)
```

Comment: Although this example ends up creating a tuple of all files that meet the filter's requirements the premise is still the same. This is also (as far as I see so far) the most "Pythonic" of all the answers.

Comment: No, it doesn't create a tuple, it creates a generator. There is no temporary tuple.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way to do this is (in 2.6 at least) is to create a filtering generator using `itertools.ifilter` and then sort it:

```
>>> from itertools import ifilter
>>> seq = [ 1, 43, 2, 10, 11, 91, 201]
>>> gen = ifilter(lambda x: x % 2 == 1, seq)
>>> sorted(gen)
[1, 11, 43, 91, 201]
```

The underlying sequence doesn't get traversed and filtered until `sorted` starts iterating over it.

Comment: This won't change what actually happens--`sorted` on an iterator still has to expand the iterator to a list.

Comment: Sure.  But that expanded list is the list that `sorted` sorts and returns.  (Admittedly, you could also use `filter` and then call `sort` on the result, which I'm pretty sure does exactly the same thing.)

Comment: Isn't this functionally equivalent to KennyTM's solution?

Comment: It is.  Really, it's hard to justify using `ifilter` instead of a generator expression.